# Linking in C using gcc

Tags: c, unix, gcc, linker

If I wanted to link the following objects and libraries,

```
p.o → libx.a → p.o
```

Where a → b denotes that b defines a symbol that is referenced by a.

Would

```
UNIX% gcc p.o libx.a
```

be enough in the command line or do I need to do something  like:

```
UNIX% gcc p.o libx.a p.o
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried it?  What error (if any) did you get?

Comment: What is it with people being scared to test stuff?  You have a computer (and a compiler, and all of the relevant code) right there!  Either it works or it doesn't.  And if it doesn't, the error message will usually tell you why.

Comment: I would say that it is generally bad practice to have circular dependency - which is what you have.

Answer (score 1):

For the record: if you're using the GNU linker, the perfect solution for you is:

`gcc -Wl,--start-group p.o libx.a -Wl,--end-group`